# Is it possible to get app only token for Azure AD where the resource or scope is https://graph.microsoft.com/?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get app only token for Azure AD where the resource or scope is https://graph.microsoft.com/?

I read the article [Service to service calls using client credentials (shared secret or certificate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service), and but I can't get an access token, the error is "fail to find resource `https://graph.microsoft.com/` in tenant xxx".

If I change `resource` to `scope`, I can get an access token, but this token can't be used to get web api. I got 401 unauthorized error. But I have granted all permissions including app and delegated permissions for the graph api.

```
POST /contoso.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=625bc9f6-3bf6-4b6d-94ba-e97cf07a22de&client_secret=qkDwDJlDfig2IpeuUZYKH1Wb8q1V0ju6sILxQQqhJ+s=&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
```

Comment: Your call seems to be correct, but the client secret needs to be URL-encoded. (Like the resource URI is)

Comment: Thanks, I found out why. I use a library to handle this, it encode the parameters, but I encode it one more time. I delete mine, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you register the Azure AD application in Azure Portal and want to acquire token for microsoft graph api using client credential flow , you should use `https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F`(url-encoded) as `resource` , and don't forget to make client secret URL-encoded as suggested by @juunas .

If you are acquiring token for your own web api which protected by Azure AD ,  you can use the  App ID URI registered for the api application as resource. Code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) is for your reference .